# Excel formula working on local but not on remote server

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am facing one very strange issue. User uploads a blank template in our system (with some formulas), service imports some data into the workbook and these formulas are triggered. I am facing a strange issue with 1 template, the formula is not working correctly (on the windows remote server) but if I copy the same workbook over to my local computer, the formula is calculating correctly. (Please note that excel automatic calculation is on)

In the remote server, if I hit calculate sheet manually nothing happens. But if I click on the cell and press enter, correct value is displayed.

I am not sure how this is possible that it works on 1 server but not on the other. Any hints on what could be the issue?

Sample formula which is not working:-

```
=IF(C$13<DATE(2021,7,31),IFERROR(Q53/G53,0),SUMIFS('foo Waterfall'!$W:$W,'foo Waterfall'!$D:$D,'bar Waterfall'!B53)+IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(('foo Threshold'!$J$6:$L$53),('foo Threshold'!$J$4:$L$4<='bar Waterfall'!$C$13)*('foo Threshold'!$C$6:$C$53='bar Waterfall'!$C53)*('foo Threshold'!$B$6:$B$53='bar Waterfall'!$B53)),0))
```

Comment: does the formula refers to other workbook. Or on the sheets within the same file?

Comment: It refers to formula on same file.

Comment: 3 things I'll try. [1] File > excel Options > Formulas {make sure all setting the same in server n local} [2] Create a new excel file, put some test formula directly on the server.. close n run. If this actually works, it means that the excel formula setting is fine, but the file permission is not.. (need 2 request xs from admin). If it had the same symptom, then it may have something to do with user access permission (need 2 request xs/help from admin). [3] "facing a strange issue with 1 template" : Try a new template?